# What is the base duration for Defense Drone?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The rank 4 evolution of the Defense Drone says that it increases the Duration by 100%. However...

[image: defense drone]

As you can see from the image above, *it doesn't list the base duration at all* on the upgrade screen. Since it obviously isn't 0 seconds, does anyone know the base duration for the Defense Drone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coalesced.bin lists the `effectduration` for the `protectordrone` (Defense Drone) object as having a base value of 45, so the default duration should be 45 seconds.

Comment: Hm, are you positive the value is in full seconds? After leveling Tali up, it definitely is *not* lasting anywhere near to that...

Comment: It should be, yep. Tactical Cloak has a known base duration of 8 seconds, and its value is 8. Were you using the drone in combat, or just trying it out in safety? There's an additional `noncombattimeout_length` that indicates it might go away more quickly in non-sustained combat, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Ahha, I think that might be it! I was indeed testing outside of combat. Thanks much! :D

Comment: Sure thing! For completeness, that timeout value is 5, so my guess is that it's only five seconds of safety before it disappears.